# Optaplanner throws NullPointerException while building solver

Tags: optaplanner

Optaplanner throws null NullPointerException while executing the below code

```
SolverFactory<ScheduleSolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource("scheduleSolverConfiguration.xml");
Solver<ScheduleSolution> a = solverFactory.buildSolver();
```

I am using ConstraintProvider instead of direct drools

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
    <scanAnnotatedClasses/>

    <scoreDirectorFactory>
        <constraintProviderClass>ScheduleConstraintProvider</constraintProviderClass>
    </scoreDirectorFactory>

    <termination>
        <secondsSpentLimit>10</secondsSpentLimit>
    </termination>
</solver>
```

Exception trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.DroolsConstraintFactory.<init>(DroolsConstraintFactory.java:51)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.stream.ConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.<init>(ConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory.java:52)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildConstraintStreamScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:563)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java:461)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildScoreDirectorFactory(SolverConfig.java:606)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:514)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildSolver(DefaultSolverFactory.java:49)
```

optaplanner version - 7.36.0

Answer (score 0):

I bet your ConstraintProvider returns null, or an array of Constraint with some elements that are null.

Regardless, OptaPlanner should give you a better error message in that case. Please create an issue issues.redhat.com project PLANNER.

Comment: No. I found the issue. The issue was in DroolsConstraintFactory class with code "this.solutionDescriptor.getSolutionClass().getPackage().getName()". Since my ScheduleSolution class is in the root, the getPackage() on the solution class return null. So, it causes NullPointerException. When I move my classes in the new sub package it worked fine

Comment: Intresting! Thanks for reporting back here. Again, OptaPlanner should report a better error message (or even allow it), I 'll make that happen.

Comment: Agreed, this should fix it: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/pull/775
Oh, and I've added a warning if anyone puts a solution class or entity class in the default package. It can be tolerable for POC's, but that's not something that may reach production. Thanks for reporting!